# Telegram Bot - Welcome Message

Tags: telegram-bot, бот

Подскажите как реализовать на python приветственное сообщение бота, только что подписавшемуся в группу в Telegram участнику? с помощью какого метода и саму схему

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1238765/234134

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете отлавливать разные события при помощи API телеграма. В том числе и новых пользователей в группе:
Ниже оставил пример реализации на Aiogram (Python):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    user_name = message.new_chat_member.first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0}!".format(user_name))
```

Этот же блок кода сработает не только на группу, но и на канал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @andreymal это сработает если автор имел ввиду отправку сообщения прямо в группе. И пользователя можно попросить в этом же сообщении самому написать боту, если есть такая необходимость.

Comment: А да, об этом я не подумал

Comment: Роман, почему то с каналом не прокатывает

Comment: File "C:/Users/timas/PycharmProjects/hello_bot/main.py", line 25, in handler_new_member
    user_name = message.new_chat_member.first_name
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'new_chat_member'