# Бот не отвечает в чате как исправить

Tags: python, telebot

вотс

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'new_chat_members'])
def info(message):
    try:

        if message.new_chat_member:

            username = f'@{str(message.from_user.username)}'
            username = username.replace('@None', str(message.from_user.first_name))

            bot.send_message(chat_worker_id, f'Привет')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: добавьте подробностей, не отвечает где? в канале\группе? отвечать должен при каком условии?

Comment: в группе, должен отвечать при заходе участника

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    try:
        if message.content_type == 'new_chat_members':
            bot.reply_to(message, f'Привет')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]